# Sencha Touch 2 & Spring Security cross-domain login

Tags: spring-security, sencha-touch-2

I need use API of some server from Sencha Touch 2 app . For using this API I need authenticate on server.

So I already implemented login functionality :

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://192.168.1.2:8080/spring-security-extjs-login/j_spring_security_check',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
                j_username: 'rod',
                j_password: 'koala',
            },
            withCredentials: false,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,

            success: function(response){
                var text = response.responseText;
        Ext.Msg.alert("success", text, Ext.emptyFn);
            },

            failure: function(response){
                var text = response.responseText;
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', text, Ext.emptyFn);
            }
});
```

But how I can call API , because after authentication I try call API but they already want authentication. Probably I need save JSESSIONID and added it to another request, but I don't know how I can do it.

I can't use  withCredentials: true , so I need to find another solution.

How I can get Set-Cookies from response HTTP Header ?

I see in Chrome console, that JSESSIONID present in response header , so , i need get it.

Please, help me find any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `requestcomplete` & `beforerequest` events to read response headers and to write request headers respectively. Here is sample code :

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestcomplete', function(conn, response, options, eOpts){
    var respObj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    Helper.setSessionId(options.headers['JSESSIONID']);
}, this);

Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function(conn, options, eOptions){
    options.headers['JSESSIONID'] = Helper.getSessionId();
}, this);
```

Comment: HI ,thanks for answer but I have another error : Cannot read property 'JSESSIONID' of undefined but it really present in response header , I saw it in browser using dev. tools

Comment: dump `options` in console and see where it is